# Unreal 4: Checking out with Git as VCS

Tags: unreal-4, version-control, unreal, git

I have my editor configured to use git as my VCS. I have my own server in which the repo is hosted.

I followed the [GIT with Unreal 4 guide](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Git_source_control_(Tutorial)).

My problem is that I cannot find the "Check Out" option in the right-click menu of any blueprint/asset. My VCS menu only shows Refresh, History and Diff Against Depot.

Am I wrong if I think that when modifying any asset, my teammates shall check out the asset in order to lock it for editing? If so, how to do that? I tried with the auto-checkout on asset modification but that's not working as expected either, since I modify an asset and it's not being checked out.

Any ideas on how to properly configure GIT to work as expected?

Moreover, how to make a push from the editor? I seem to be able to make the commit by "Checking In" some asset, but can I make the push to the remote repo from the editor itself?

Many thanks.